# Is it possible to attach a description field to the records in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

In SQL Server, `[database name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` has the following columns:

- TABLE_CATALOG
- TABLE_SCHEMA
- TABLE_NAME
- TABLE_TYPE

This table has no additional fields, such as "DESCRIPTION"

This is confirmed by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx).

My question is this: other than making a manual database or a Word document of my own, is there a system or other column or table that I can use to store a "description" or "memo" value per record in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` table?

To deal with this as much as possible I use database, table, and field naming conventions, but that can go only so far. Some of the names have a "back story" that can be explained to future team members in a "description" field.

I have tried so far:

- Google searches for related questions.
- Looking for a "description" field of the table properties in SSMS (see screenshot below), but it wasn't what I had in mind.

Is there any preexisting field in a system or other table that I am missing and matches my need?

[image: SSMS Table Properties]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use extended properties.  It's not in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views but it will stay attached to that object.

I wrote about it in detail here: https://sqlstudies.com/2015/05/18/extending-your-metadata-with-extended-properties/

But here is what it would look like attached to a User:

[image]

Here is how you would query all of the extended properties for users in a given database:

```
-- View the extended properties
SELECT ep.*, dp.name FROM sys.extended_properties ep
JOIN sys.database_principals dp
    ON ep.major_id = dp.principal_id
WHERE class_desc = 'DATABASE_PRINCIPAL'
GO
```

The same thing will work for pretty much any object in SQL Server.  Obviously you'd want to modify the query somewhat but that should be pretty easy.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for. Can you give me a "hello world" type of example?

Comment: Added an example using a USER & tied to a blog post on the subject.  Does that help?